# Cannot Play Exoplayer video with assets folder

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to play Video with ExoPlayer, but unfortunately I cannot find any solution.Please help me I've been scratching my head for two days but can't find anything.

This is my code when preparing and setting exoPlayer properties.

```
String path = "asset:///splash_video.mp4";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), new DefaultTrackSelector(), new DefaultLoadControl());
    DataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(this, getPackageName()));
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), new Handler(), null);
    player.prepare(extractorMediaSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Also I've been following this link from youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwImlEfitQU

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852975/exoplayer-reading-mp3-file-from-raw-folder) may help.

Comment: I also use this approach but not working. Also exoplayer cannot read file from raw folder it says here.                                                                                    <https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/556>@ADM

Comment: There are same issues discussed on Git too . You can have a look there too .

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code is working for audio files,working fine and tested ok:
You just pass file name which should be like 001 is the file in ***assets\001.mp3***

you should call the function like this:

```
prepareExoPlayerFromAssetResourceFile(001);
```

the code is:

```
    private void prepareExoPlayerFromAssetResourceFile(int current_file) {

    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector((TrackSelection.Factory) null), new DefaultLoadControl());
    exoPlayer.addListener(eventListener);


    //DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(Uri.parse("asset:///001.mp3"));
    DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(Uri.parse("asset:///" + (current_file))+".mp3");
    final AssetDataSource assetDataSource = new AssetDataSource(this);
    try {
        assetDataSource.open(dataSpec);
    } catch (AssetDataSource.AssetDataSourceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            //return rawResourceDataSource;
            return assetDataSource;
        }
    };

    MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(assetDataSource.getUri(),
            factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);



   /*
    MediaSource audioSource1 = new ExtractorMediaSource(
            Uri.parse("asset:///" + getfileName(current_file)), // file audio ada di folder assets
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory  (),
            null,
            null
    );

    */
    exoPlayer.prepare(audioSource);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to set appt compress config in build.gradle(app).

```
android {
  ...
  aaptOptions{
    noCompress "mp4" // file extesion
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DefaultDataSourceFactory instead of a DefaultHttpDataSourcFactory:

```
new ExtractorMediaSource(
    Uri.parse("asset://splash_video.mp4"),
    new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, userAgent),
    new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
    null,
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder "raw" inside your application's "res" folder and copy the file to the newly created folder and replace,

```
   ExtractorMediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(
            Uri.parse("asset:///" + current_file), // file audio ada di folder assets
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
            null,
            null
    );
```

this code with,

```
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://Your Package Name/" + R.raw.welcome_video);
   ExtractorMediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(
            Uri.parse("uri ), // file audio ada di folder assets
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
            null,
            null
    );
```